# Get currently playing file in VLC using CLI

Tags: macos, terminal, vlc-media-player

Is there a way I can run a command in my Terminal to copy the current playing file path in VLC file into a specified location?

e.g. the current file `/user/imran/example.mp3` would be copied to `/user/imran/desktop/example.mp3`?

I am using VLC on Mac OS X

Answer (score 0):

In its default configuration, I don't think there is an easy way to do this.  However, if you enable the HTTP interface (View -> Add Interface -> Web or `-I http`) you can query the playlist to get the current playing track information.  Query the URL:

```
http://localhost:8080/requests/playlist_jstree.xml
```

This will return an XML document with the playlist information.  The current playing `<item>` will have the attribute `current="current"`.  A sample document is below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes" ?>
<root>
    <item id="plid_2" name="Playlist" ro="ro">
        <content>
            <name>Playlist</name>
        </content>
        <item id="plid_4" uri="file:///<PATH_TO_MEDIA_FILE>.mp4" name="<MEDIA_FILE>.mp4" ro="rw" duration ="10" current="current" >
            <content>
                <name><MEDIA_FILE>.mp4</name>
            </content>
        </item>
    </item>
</root>
```

Comment: Could you add some information on how I could then use the xml to parse the now playing URI from a CLI?