# Copy currently playing file in VLC using Terminal

Tags: macos, terminal, vlc-media-player, console

I would like to be able to get the currently playing file in my VLC player and copy the file into a specified directory.

I would like to know how I can do this using VLC's console interface to get the path of the currently playing file and `cp` it.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Get currently playing file in VLC using CLI](http://superuser.com/q/991400/162491).